# gorilla golang websocket.IsUnexpectedCloseError not working correctly under windows?

Tags: windows, go, websocket, gorilla

I have a routine that tries to detect if a websocket error while reading is an UnexpectedCloseError.
This is the code...

having a variable:

```
myWebsocket                      *websocket.Conn
```

my method is:

```
messageType, data, err := myWebsocket.ReadMessage()
if err != nil {
    if websocket.IsUnexpectedCloseError(err) {
        log.Debugf("WebsocketReadDataMessage: unexpected close error: %v", err)
    } else {
        log.Warnf("EXTRANGE!!!!: WebsocketReadDataMessage: error: %v", err)
    }
    return err
}
```

Running this code under windows sometimes the websocket closes but the call to websocket.IsUnexpectedCloseError returns "false" and I get an error with the text "EXTRANGE!!!!: WebsocketReadDataMessage: error:  wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Searching for "wsarecv" and I have seen that it is a winsock2 function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsarecv

Why IsUnexpectedCloseError doesn't treat this error as an "UnexpectedCloseError"? Is it a bug or maybe I'm doing something wrong? What can I do to

Comment: Thanks for your answer Cerise. I was trying to differentiate if an read error occurs because of an unexpected websocket close or not. I will try to reopen the websocket if it is an unexpected close.  I can't understand why an error that says "wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host." is not a *websocket.CloseError.

Comment: And how can I know if the underlying network connection of a websocket has been closed and that I need to reopen the websocket connection as this is the case with the "wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host." error?

Answer (score 1):

The function `websocket.IsUnexpectedCloseError()` works correctly on Windows. There is no platform dependent code in the function.

The function [websocket.IsUnexpectedCloseError](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket#IsUnexpectedCloseError) returns a boolean indicating whether the error is a `*websocket.CloseError` with a code not in the list of expected codes.  A `*websocket.CloseError` represents a [close message](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-5.5.1) sent from the peer. A `*websocket.CloseError` does not indicate that the underlying network connection was closed. According the example in the documentation, the function is intended to aid debugging.

It sounds like your goal is to determine when the connection is no longer useable. The connection is not useable after `ReadMessage()` returns any error.  Close the connection and reconnect on any error.

```
messageType, data, err := myWebsocket.ReadMessage()
if err != nil {
    myWebsocket.Close()
    return err
}
```